# PhoneFactor Country List

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm using the **PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify** for my custom policy MFA. If a user does not have a phone number registered, it will ask them to enter one. Part of this is a dropdown list of countries that the phone is registered in (so that it can get the country code). I've managed to trim this list down to just a few countries, using the following TechnicalProfile

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify">
    <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.PhoneFactorProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.phonefactor</Item>
        <Item Key="ManualPhoneNumberEntryAllowed">true</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.authenticationMode">sms</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.autodial">true</Item>     
        <Item Key="language.countryList"><![CDATA[{"IE": "Ireland","IM": "Isle of Man","GB": "United Kingdom","US": "United States","DE": "Germany"}]]></Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserIdForMFA" />
    </InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdForMFA" PartnerClaimType="UserId" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="Verified.OfficePhone" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPhoneNumberEntered" PartnerClaimType="newPhoneNumberEntered" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isActiveMFASession" DefaultValue="true"/>
    </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

The problem is that it always defaults to the United States, I want to be able to set what country code the dropdown defaults to. Anyone know how I do this?

I've tried adding `"DEFAULT": "United Kingdom",` to the start of the JSON however, just just adds another selection to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried moving `"GB": "United Kingdom"` in front of the list and removing `"DEFAULT": "Country/Region"` ?

Another possibility is to use Java Script to customize the dropdown but would only recommend that if this behavior is not achievable via policy.

Here is a working example where I have updated the policy to use [language customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-localization) feature in B2C. Basically moved the GB at the top of Country_List item and remove entry for DEFAULT.

[image]

```
{
  "LocalizedStrings": [
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "alternative_text",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "I don't have my phone"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "button_cancel",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Cancel"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "button_retry",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Retry"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "button_send_code",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Send Code"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "button_verify",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Call Me"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "button_verify_code",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Verify Code"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "cancel_message",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "The user has cancelled multi-factor authentication"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "code_pattern",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "\\d{6}"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "countryList",
      "Override": true,
      "Value": "{\"GB\":\"United Kingdom\", \"AF\":\"Afghanistan\",\"AX\":\"Åland Islands\",\"AL\":\"Albania\",\"DZ\":\"Algeria\",\"AS\":\"American Samoa\",\"AD\":\"Andorra\",\"AO\":\"Angola\",\"AI\":\"Anguilla\",\"AQ\":\"Antarctica\",\"AG\":\"Antigua and Barbuda\",\"AR\":\"Argentina\",\"AM\":\"Armenia\",\"AW\":\"Aruba\",\"AU\":\"Australia\",\"AT\":\"Austria\",\"AZ\":\"Azerbaijan\",\"BS\":\"Bahamas\",\"BH\":\"Bahrain\",\"BD\":\"Bangladesh\",\"BB\":\"Barbados\",\"BY\":\"Belarus\",\"BE\":\"Belgium\",\"BZ\":\"Belize\",\"BJ\":\"Benin\",\"BM\":\"Bermuda\",\"BT\":\"Bhutan\",\"BO\":\"Bolivia\",\"BQ\":\"Bonaire\",\"BA\":\"Bosnia and Herzegovina\",\"BW\":\"Botswana\",\"BV\":\"Bouvet Island\",\"BR\":\"Brazil\",\"IO\":\"British Indian Ocean Territory\",\"VG\":\"British Virgin Islands\",\"BN\":\"Brunei\",\"BG\":\"Bulgaria\",\"BF\":\"Burkina Faso\",\"BI\":\"Burundi\",\"CV\":\"Cabo Verde\",\"KH\":\"Cambodia\",\"CM\":\"Cameroon\",\"CA\":\"Canada\",\"KY\":\"Cayman Islands\",\"CF\":\"Central African Republic\",\"TD\":\"Chad\",\"CL\":\"Chile\",\"CN\":\"China\",\"CX\":\"Christmas Island\",\"CC\":\"Cocos (Keeling) Islands\",\"CO\":\"Colombia\",\"KM\":\"Comoros\",\"CG\":\"Congo\",\"CD\":\"Congo (DRC)\",\"CK\":\"Cook Islands\",\"CR\":\"Costa Rica\",\"CI\":\"Côte d’Ivoire\",\"HR\":\"Croatia\",\"CU\":\"Cuba\",\"CW\":\"Curaçao\",\"CY\":\"Cyprus\",\"CZ\":\"Czechia\",\"DK\":\"Denmark\",\"DJ\":\"Djibouti\",\"DM\":\"Dominica\",\"DO\":\"Dominican Republic\",\"EC\":\"Ecuador\",\"EG\":\"Egypt\",\"SV\":\"El Salvador\",\"GQ\":\"Equatorial Guinea\",\"ER\":\"Eritrea\",\"EE\":\"Estonia\",\"SZ\":\"Eswatini\",\"ET\":\"Ethiopia\",\"FK\":\"Falkland Islands\",\"FO\":\"Faroe Islands\",\"FJ\":\"Fiji\",\"FI\":\"Finland\",\"FR\":\"France\",\"GF\":\"French Guiana\",\"PF\":\"French Polynesia\",\"TF\":\"French Southern Territories\",\"GA\":\"Gabon\",\"GM\":\"Gambia\",\"GE\":\"Georgia\",\"DE\":\"Germany\",\"GH\":\"Ghana\",\"GI\":\"Gibraltar\",\"GR\":\"Greece\",\"GL\":\"Greenland\",\"GD\":\"Grenada\",\"GP\":\"Guadeloupe\",\"GU\":\"Guam\",\"GT\":\"Guatemala\",\"GG\":\"Guernsey\",\"GN\":\"Guinea\",\"GW\":\"Guinea-Bissau\",\"GY\":\"Guyana\",\"HT\":\"Haiti\",\"HM\":\"Heard Island and McDonald Islands\",\"HN\":\"Honduras\",\"HK\":\"Hong Kong SAR\",\"HU\":\"Hungary\",\"IS\":\"Iceland\",\"IN\":\"India\",\"ID\":\"Indonesia\",\"IR\":\"Iran\",\"IQ\":\"Iraq\",\"IE\":\"Ireland\",\"IM\":\"Isle of Man\",\"IL\":\"Israel\",\"IT\":\"Italy\",\"JM\":\"Jamaica\",\"JP\":\"Japan\",\"JE\":\"Jersey\",\"JO\":\"Jordan\",\"KZ\":\"Kazakhstan\",\"KE\":\"Kenya\",\"KI\":\"Kiribati\",\"KR\":\"Korea\",\"KW\":\"Kuwait\",\"KG\":\"Kyrgyzstan\",\"LA\":\"Laos\",\"LV\":\"Latvia\",\"LB\":\"Lebanon\",\"LS\":\"Lesotho\",\"LR\":\"Liberia\",\"LY\":\"Libya\",\"LI\":\"Liechtenstein\",\"LT\":\"Lithuania\",\"LU\":\"Luxembourg\",\"MO\":\"Macao SAR\",\"MG\":\"Madagascar\",\"MW\":\"Malawi\",\"MY\":\"Malaysia\",\"MV\":\"Maldives\",\"ML\":\"Mali\",\"MT\":\"Malta\",\"MH\":\"Marshall Islands\",\"MQ\":\"Martinique\",\"MR\":\"Mauritania\",\"MU\":\"Mauritius\",\"YT\":\"Mayotte\",\"MX\":\"Mexico\",\"FM\":\"Micronesia\",\"MD\":\"Moldova\",\"MC\":\"Monaco\",\"MN\":\"Mongolia\",\"ME\":\"Montenegro\",\"MS\":\"Montserrat\",\"MA\":\"Morocco\",\"MZ\":\"Mozambique\",\"MM\":\"Myanmar\",\"NA\":\"Namibia\",\"NR\":\"Nauru\",\"NP\":\"Nepal\",\"NL\":\"Netherlands\",\"NC\":\"New Caledonia\",\"NZ\":\"New Zealand\",\"NI\":\"Nicaragua\",\"NE\":\"Niger\",\"NG\":\"Nigeria\",\"NU\":\"Niue\",\"NF\":\"Norfolk Island\",\"KP\":\"North Korea\",\"MK\":\"North Macedonia\",\"MP\":\"Northern Mariana Islands\",\"NO\":\"Norway\",\"OM\":\"Oman\",\"PK\":\"Pakistan\",\"PW\":\"Palau\",\"PS\":\"Palestinian Authority\",\"PA\":\"Panama\",\"PG\":\"Papua New Guinea\",\"PY\":\"Paraguay\",\"PE\":\"Peru\",\"PH\":\"Philippines\",\"PN\":\"Pitcairn Islands\",\"PL\":\"Poland\",\"PT\":\"Portugal\",\"PR\":\"Puerto Rico\",\"QA\":\"Qatar\",\"RE\":\"Réunion\",\"RO\":\"Romania\",\"RU\":\"Russia\",\"RW\":\"Rwanda\",\"BL\":\"Saint Barthélemy\",\"KN\":\"Saint Kitts and Nevis\",\"LC\":\"Saint Lucia\",\"MF\":\"Saint Martin\",\"PM\":\"Saint Pierre and Miquelon\",\"VC\":\"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines\",\"WS\":\"Samoa\",\"SM\":\"San Marino\",\"ST\":\"São Tomé and Príncipe\",\"SA\":\"Saudi Arabia\",\"SN\":\"Senegal\",\"RS\":\"Serbia\",\"SC\":\"Seychelles\",\"SL\":\"Sierra Leone\",\"SG\":\"Singapore\",\"SX\":\"Sint Maarten\",\"SK\":\"Slovakia\",\"SI\":\"Slovenia\",\"SB\":\"Solomon Islands\",\"SO\":\"Somalia\",\"ZA\":\"South Africa\",\"GS\":\"South Georgia and South Sandwich Islands\",\"SS\":\"South Sudan\",\"ES\":\"Spain\",\"LK\":\"Sri Lanka\",\"SH\":\"St Helena, Ascension, Tristan da Cunha\",\"SD\":\"Sudan\",\"SR\":\"Suriname\",\"SJ\":\"Svalbard\",\"SE\":\"Sweden\",\"CH\":\"Switzerland\",\"SY\":\"Syria\",\"TW\":\"Taiwan\",\"TJ\":\"Tajikistan\",\"TZ\":\"Tanzania\",\"TH\":\"Thailand\",\"TL\":\"Timor-Leste\",\"TG\":\"Togo\",\"TK\":\"Tokelau\",\"TO\":\"Tonga\",\"TT\":\"Trinidad and Tobago\",\"TN\":\"Tunisia\",\"TR\":\"Turkey\",\"TM\":\"Turkmenistan\",\"TC\":\"Turks and Caicos Islands\",\"TV\":\"Tuvalu\",\"UM\":\"U.S. Outlying Islands\",\"VI\":\"U.S. Virgin Islands\",\"UG\":\"Uganda\",\"UA\":\"Ukraine\",\"AE\":\"United Arab Emirates\",\"US\":\"United States\",\"UY\":\"Uruguay\",\"UZ\":\"Uzbekistan\",\"VU\":\"Vanuatu\",\"VA\":\"Vatican City\",\"VE\":\"Venezuela\",\"VN\":\"Vietnam\",\"WF\":\"Wallis and Futuna\",\"YE\":\"Yemen\",\"ZM\":\"Zambia\",\"ZW\":\"Zimbabwe\"}"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "country_code_input_placeholder_text",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Country or region"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "country_code_label",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Country Code"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "enter_code_text_intro",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Enter your verification code below, or "
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "error_448",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "The phone number you provided is unreachable."
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "error_449",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "User has exceeded the number of retry attempts."
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "error_incorrect_code",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "The verification code you have entered does not match our records. Please try again, or request a new code."
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "error_tryagain",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "The phone number you provided is busy or unavailable. Please check the number and try again."
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "intro_entry_mixed",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Enter a number below that we can send a code via SMS or phone to authenticate you."
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "intro_entry_phone",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Enter a number below that we can phone to authenticate you."
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "intro_entry_sms",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Enter a number below that we can send a code via SMS to authenticate you."
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "intro_mixed",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "We have the following number on record for you. We can send a code via SMS or phone to authenticate you."
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "intro_mixed_p",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "We have the following numbers on record for you. Choose a number that we can phone or send a code via SMS to authenticate you."
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "intro_phone",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "We have the following number on record for you. We will phone to authenticate you."
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "intro_phone_p",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "We have the following numbers on record for you.  Choose a number that we can phone to authenticate you."
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "intro_sms",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "We have the following number on record for you. We will send a code via SMS to authenticate you."
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "intro_sms_p",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "We have the following numbers on record for you. Choose a number that we can send a code via SMS to authenticate you."
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "invalid_code",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Please enter the 6 digit code you received"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "invalid_number",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Please enter a valid phone number"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "local_number_input_placeholder_text",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Phone number"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "number_label",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Phone Number"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "number_pattern",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "^\\+(?:[0-9][\\x20-]?){6,14}[0-9]$"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "requiredField_code",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Please enter the verification code you received"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "requiredField_countryCode",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Please select your country code"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "requiredField_number",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Please enter your phone number"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "text_button_send_second_code",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "send a new code"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "verification_code_input_placeholder_text",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Verification code"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Currently it’s defaulting to the US, which is 4th in the list. Hoping to avoid using JavaScript as that could cause other issue.

Comment: So  this does not work to make UK the first choice?      <Item Key="language.countryList"><![CDATA[{ "GB": "United Kingdom", "IE": "Ireland","IM": "Isle of Man","US": "United States","DE": "Germany"}]]></Item>

Comment: No if I take the default out, it still defaults to the US :(

Comment: Can you try updating the language file and then use that into your policy instead of using metadata in the technical profile? You can look at the sample one that I have added above. It is working as expected after putting GB first and removing Default. This led me to believe that there is something not right with the metadata approach in the technical profile.

Comment: Sorry, may have missed bits of your answer as I was using the iPad app over the weekend to read it. I have just refactored my policy files to move the language setting into the ContentDefinition as you suggested and that works. 

Must admit does not make sense not working both ways, but at least got it working. Thanks